# displaying html from a "php foreach" on a fixed number of columns

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code:

```
<?php if(count($this->items)): ?>
        <section class="itemList">
                <?php foreach ($this->items as $item): ?>
                <...>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </section>
```

<...> represents item title, description etc... for each item: how can i work on css/html to make those items to be displayed on a fixed number of rows, say 3, instead of on a unique long column?
Thanks to anybody who can help

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CSS3 you can use the propery `-webkit-column-count:3; -moz-column-count:3; column-count:3;`. Otherwise you have to do it in a different way (splitting it up in your PHP code).

Comment: nice! problem: now i've items divided in 3 columns, but when the number of items is not multiple of 3, items are splitted on different columns... is there a way to avoid this???

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<?php if(count($this->items)): ?>
    <section class="itemList">
            <?php foreach ($this->items as $item){
                $x++;
                if($x % 3 == 0){
                    ?><br><?php
                }?>
            <...>
            <?php } ?>
    </section>
```